# Symfony2 - "Killed" process when clearing cache for production environment

Tags: php, symfony

Suddenly, when I type `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` as `www-data` user, the console only outputs:

> Killed

With development environment it is working right. I thought it could be a permissions issue, so I did:

```
sudo chown -R www-data app/cache
```

but the issue persists. Any idea of why is it happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Ran out of RAM maybe?

Comment: @usoban - I don't think so, because no errors are thrown, but I'll try increasing it.

Comment: @usoban - You were right. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

7 years later, but I'll leave my solution if you get to this page.

Had the same problem with a clean install of Symfony 4 on PHP 7.4, all console commands return "Killed". I downgraded PHP to 7.2 and it works OK.

Comment: Fix the code instead of downgrading entire environment to a less secure PHP version.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific: I was running a *clean* Symfony 4 installation. There's no code to fix, except maybe Symfony itself.